# Using pyserial to send binary data

Tags: python, pyserial

I know there has been a lot of discussion on this but I still have a question. I am trying to send hex values through pyserial to my device using pyserial

```
command="\x89\x45\x56"
ser.write(command)
```

However I keep getting an error saying  `string argument without encoding.` Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Why not use `binascii`? `from binascii import unhexlify`, and then `command = unhexlify("894556")`

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  And what's the full traceback look like?

Answer (score 17):

```
packet = bytearray()
packet.append(0x41)
packet.append(0x42)
packet.append(0x43)

ser.write(packet)
```

Comment: I found this particularly helpful for sending code-page translated byte streams.  Application uses old Code Page 437.

Answer (score 9):

From pySerial API [documentation](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.write):

> **write(data)**  Write the bytes data to the port. This should be of type bytes (or compatible such as bytearray or memoryview). Unicode strings must be encoded (e.g. 'hello'.encode('utf-8').

Assuming you're working on Python 3 (you should), this is the way to send a single byte:

```
command = b'\x61' # 'a' character in hex
ser.write(command)
```

For several bytes:

```
command = b'\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f' # 'Hello' string in hex
ser.write(command)
```

Answer (score 3):

I have had success sending hex values from a string like so:

```
input = '736e7000ae01FF'    
ser.write(input.decode("hex"))
print "sending",input.decode("hex")

>> sending snp «☺
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is Python 3, it's probably treating your string as unicode, and doesn't know how to transform it.  I think you probably mean to use bytes here:

```
command=b"\x89\x45\x56"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Python 3 you can use a `bytes` object.

```
command=b"\x89\x45\x56"
```

From the error it looks like pyserial tries to convert a (your) string into a bytes object without specifying an encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

Finally, I figure out how to read the specify region of binary file and send through uart (as flow control).

```
    binary_file = open("test_small.jpg", 'rb')
    filesize = getSize(binary_file)
    ser = serial.Serial('COM7', 115200, timeout=0.5)
    count = 0
    while (offset < filesize):
        binary_file.seek(offset, 0)
        ser.write(binary_file.read(MTU))
        offset = offset + MTU
```