# Can’t read register of Modbus using python via 485

Tags: python, modbus, rs485

The transducer is modbus.  Via R485
I want to send the request x00 and read it back. x00 is to read the temperature

The transducer is expecting hex example: x00

```py
import serial           # import the module
ComPort = serial.Serial('COM4') # open COM4

ComPort.baudrate = 9600 # set Baud rate to 9600
ComPort.bytesize = 8    # Number of data bits = 8
ComPort.parity   = 'N'  # No parity
ComPort.stopbits = 1    # Number of Stop bits = 1


ComPort.write.encode(hex(00))
ComPort.read()
print(ComPort.read())

ComPort.close()         # Close the Com port
```

This is my error:

```
line 13, in <module>
    ComPort.write.encode(hex(00))

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: `.read()` takes an integer as an argument https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read

Comment: Your code makes no sense at all. If your transducer does indeed work with Modbus then sending that byte stream of zeros makes no sense either. First, make sure whether your sensor supports Modbus or a proprietary serial protocol. If it's Modbus then you can try using [pyModbus](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial), that should make your life much easier. Of course, you can also send Modbus frames as raw serial data as you are trying to do but first, you need to compose proper Modbus requests. You can try something like [this](https://rapidscada.net/modbus/).

Comment: You're missing the close paren for the `write` call. That's the syntax error. No comment on the rest.

Comment: First: you should do `ComPort.write(b'\x00)`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589942/using-pyserial-to-send-binary-data) and second you need to either increase the default timeout with `ComPort = serial.Serial('COM4', timeout=5)` or introduce a short delay with `time.sleep()` after writing and before reading for the device to have some time to process and send its response. And I will say it again: if your device is expecting Modbus sending it a single byte ain't gonna work

Comment: Solved! thanks guys for the bits of cheese. I could not just send a  single command pyserial does not compute crc for you. i had to send all 8 of the "query frame"

Comment: great, maybe you can write an answer to let others know what was wrong and how you solved it. I will certainly upvote both the answer and the question if you write it. Cheers.

Comment: Please do not update the question with different questions as you are fixing an issue, ending up with a question which has no error in the end, as you did here. The point of SO is not to provide free debugging for you, it is to keep records of problems encountered by developers in the past, so that future readers who have the same issues can find solutions. Therefore, when you find a solution, keep the question as it is and post the solution as an answer to that question (unless there already is an answer with that solution, in which case you need not do anything).

Comment: @kurta I rolled back to the version that doesn't contain the solution. As zvone said, solutions should be posted as an answer.

Comment: Thats fine  as long as the solution is posted .

Answer (score 1):

What I was doing wrong was not following the Modbus protocol. Modbus requires all segments as shown here.

```
command = (b'\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x02\xC4\x0B')
#command = x01 address x03 function code x0000 starting address x0001
#data length xC40B is CRC(check code)
```

A [friendly link](https://www.simplymodbus.ca/FAQ.htm#CRC) to a crc calculator.